# Does fixed positioned element always stay above all the other divs?

Tags: html, css

I have a project: the name (div "h_name") has a fixed position. It's the first div in body, so it should, as I know, stay under all the elements. Unfortunately, somehow it stays above everything. How do I make it go under all other divs? Z-index doesn't work for it too.

Codepen -- https://codepen.io/polina-sotnikova/pen/VwQyXYG

```
<h1 class="h_name">dyslexia</h1>
```

Comment: z-index:-1 but if all your text is black, above or below won't make any visual difference

Answer (score 0):

You need a background on the content element or the stacking order will make no difference to what you see on the page. Here is a very simplified example based on the code you provided:

```css
.h_name {
  ...
  background:red;
  z-index:-1;
}
.header {
  background:blue;
}
```

And a full snippet here: https://codepen.io/29b6/pen/KKQZoMg

Comment: Oh, Omid, thank you! I just found out what the problem was. The solution with z-index works perfectly in chrome, but when I open this page in Safari h_name disappears...

Comment: I just tried the pen in safari and the `h_name` behaved correctly. Maybe I've misunderstood you  - can you elaborate or link to another example?

Answer (score 0):

use a id for your class and apply below css.Hope it works...

HTML

```
<h1 class="h_name" id="h_name">dyslexia</h1>
```

CSS

```
#h_name{
  z-index:-1!important;
}
```